# IO / HTTP error in Uploadify

Tags: c#, asp.net, uploadify

I am trying to get uploadify to work. When I try and upload something the browse functionality works fine but there is a breif pause and then I get either an "http error" or an "IO error".

The progress bar doesn't display, which made me think it might be a path issue, but the swf file is in the same location as the images / scripts which it appears to be finding OK.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: I have the same problem. 

I am experiencing it on my production system which is running nginx and passenger (EngineYard). 

However, it works fine on my localhost :(

What type of environment are you on?

Comment: Have you found solution for your problem....

Comment: Have you given folder permissions to the folder you're uploading files?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use a generic handler (`.ashx`) for receiving the file? Here is my code

```
Public Class Video_File_Upload
    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler
    'Dim File_Path_Chapter_Video As String = "XXX/"
    Dim Directory_Videos As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Videos_Save")
    Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
        context.Response.Expires = -1
        Try
            Dim postedFile As HttpPostedFile = context.Request.Files("Filedata")
            Dim filename As String = postedFile.FileName
            'string folderName = context.Request.QueryString["FolderName"];
            Dim NOF As String
            Dim CheckFilePath As String
            Dim MapPath As String
            NOF = Convert.ToString(context.Request("NOF"))
            CheckFilePath = Directory_Videos & NOF
            If Directory.Exists(CheckFilePath) = False Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(CheckFilePath)
            End If
            MapPath = Directory_Videos & NOF & "/" & filename
            postedFile.SaveAs(MapPath)
        Catch

        End Try
    End Sub

    ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Then you have to put this line in the upload setting: "uploadScript:Video_File_Upload.ashx"